# How to add the output of wc -l at the end of each line in csv files using awk or sed

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to add the output of `wc -l` at the end of every line in files. if a file has 20 records/lines, I want to add the number, 20 at the end of each line in that file, if the next file has 100 records/lines, add the, 100 at the end of each line. I tried the below command but did not do what i wanted.

```
awk -v char=$(wc -l FILENAME | cut -f1 -d' ') '{print $0"," char}' FILENAME
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an odd request, but this should do what you want.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

for f in *.csv; do
   size="$(wc -l <$f)"
   sed -i "s/$/,$size/g" "$f"
done

exit
```

Be warned that this will edit in-place every `.csv` file in your current directory.

EDIT: on Mac your `sed` command may have to be `sed -i '.bak' "s/$/, $size/g" "$f"` because the backup extension may be required.  This doesn't work on my Linux box, though.

Comment: this works really well. well thought out.

Comment: the only problem is that it adds a space right after the ,. so it looks like , 10 instead of ,10

Comment: @danielcaceres So just delete the space in the `sed` command then...... `sed -i "s/$/,$size/g" "$f"`

Comment: @danielcaceres That wasn't entire clear based on your question, but I edited the answer to remove the space.  Could you mark this as the accepted answer if it works for you?  Gotta get those points.

Answer (score 0):

Its not awk, but it works easy

```
number=$(wc -l $1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
sed -i "s/\$/ ${number}/" $1
```

or if you like have it in one line:

```
sed -i "s/\$/ $(wc -l $file | cut -d ' ' -f 1)/" $file
```

### Example:

```
user@server 22:59:58:/tmp$ file='FILENAME'
user@server 23:00:07:/tmp$ for ((i=0; i < 10; i++)) ; do echo 123 >> "$file"; done
user@server 23:00:18:/tmp$ cat "$file"
123
123
123
123
123
123
123
123
123
123
user@server 23:00:25:/tmp$ wc -l "$file"
10 FILENAME
user@server 23:00:30:/tmp$ sed -i "s/\$/ $(wc -l "$file" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)/" "$file"
user@server 23:00:37:/tmp$ cat "$file"
123 10
123 10
123 10
123 10
123 10
123 10
123 10
123 10
123 10
123 10
user@server 23:00:39:/tmp$
user@server 23:01:54:/tmp$ ls -lA "$file"
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 70 Dez  4 23:00 FILENAME
```

Comment: it does not work for me. it just hung.

Comment: @danielcaceres cloud you please explain your error?, see my example

Comment: ok. I see what you are doing. two things, first it should add ,10 since is a csv file. second you are doing it for one file. should be able to handle multiple csv files in one run.

Comment: @danielcaceres then do this: `for file in $(ls -1 *.csv); do sed -i "s/\$/ $(wc -l $file | cut -d ' ' -f 1)/" $file; done`

Comment: i tried your example. and this is what i get.$ sed -i "s/\$/ $(wc -l $file | cut -d ' ' -f 1)/" $file
sed: 1: "FILENAME": invalid command code F

Comment: danielcaceres$ for file in $(ls -1 *.csv); do sed -i "s/\$/ $(wc -l $file | cut -d ' ' -f 1)/" $file; done
sed: 1: "t1.csv": undefined label '1.csv'
sed: 1: "t2.csv": undefined label '2.csv'
sed: 1: "t3.csv": undefined label '3.csv

Comment: @danielcaceres you have to replace `$file` with your filename (and path) or set the variable `file=FILENAME.csv`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69713/discussion-between-faxmax-and-daniel-caceres).

Comment: @danielcaceres Since you are using Mac OS (which would be worth mentioning in the question), refer to this question: [sed command with -i option failing on Mac, but works on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-with-i-option-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux). The `-i` may be your culprit! Also, if you use `wc -l < file` instead of `wc -l file`, you don't need to use `cut` and you will get only the number.

Comment: @FaxMax This is not a good solution.  Parsing the output of `ls`, not quoting variable names, unnecessary use of pipes and `cut`, and to top it all off in your example you're logged in as root...

Comment: @m0dular i was too lazy, and i had no other shell. Depending on the file permissions root privileges are not necessary. But what is wrong with `$(ls -1 *.csv)`

Comment: @FaxMax it will fail horribly if your files contain whitespace characters as the result undergoes word-splitting. Never iterate over output of `ls`! Globbing is always the better option.

Comment: Hi Folks, what would be a good final solution? what does the code needs to look like. appreciated.

Comment: @danielcaceres Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

A solution in pure awk:

```
awk '
  # Read the file and print it with the additional column
  function process_file( SIZE, FILE,    NEW_FILE ) {
    NEW_FILE = FILE ".tmp"
    while ( ( getline < FILE ) > 0 ){
      print $0 "," SIZE > NEW_FILE
    }
    close( FILE )
    close( NEW_FILE )
    system( "mv -f " NEW_FILE " " FILE )
  }

  # File name has changed, we just passed the end of a file,
  # => print the current file
  ( NR > 1 ) && ( PREV_FILE != FILENAME ) {
    process_file( OLD_FNR, PREV_FILE )
  }

  {
    # Save the current file name and line number within the file
    PREV_FILE = FILENAME
    OLD_FNR = FNR
  }

  END {
    # Print the last file, if any
    if ( PREV_FILE != "" ) {
      process_file( OLD_FNR, PREV_FILE )
    }
  }' file1 file2 ...
```

It is much easier with **gawk**, which has an **ENDFILE** condition:

```
gawk '
  # Read the file and print it with the additional column
  function process_file( SIZE, FILE,    NEW_FILE ){
    NEW_FILE = FILE ".tmp"
    while ( ( getline < FILE ) > 0 ){
      print $0 "," SIZE > NEW_FILE
    }
    close( FILE )
    close( NEW_FILE )
    system( "mv -f " NEW_FILE " " FILE )
  }
  # End of a file, print the file
  # FILENAME is the name of the current file being read
  # FNR is the line number within the file
  ENDFILE {
    process_file( FNR, FILENAME )
  }' file1 file2 ...
```

Comment: can i replace file1 file2 ...with *.csv . I like to be able to do it in one run for all csv files in current directory without specifying the file names.

Comment: You can use *.csv. Be careful, files will be modified in place. Keep a backup.

Comment: I have not tried the gawk solution yet. The pure AWK gets the job done. i have two questions for you. First one, how can I add (concatenate) to the count the date & time? so I get something like 1000510. The second one, how can i put the awk code in loop like for file in. I am more interested in the first question.

Comment: I am not quite sure which date format you want to use. Just change the line `print $0 "," SIZE > NEW_FILE` to add the date. For example, to add the current date (YYYYMMDD) after the size, change this line to `print $0 "," SIZE strftime("%Y%m%d") > NEW_FILE`.

Comment: You can convert the command to a script by replacing the first line by `#!/usr/bin/gawk -f` and the last line by a single `}`. Then call it with the file name as parameter.

Comment: this is the piece of code I was working with-->awk 'function process_file( SIZE, FILE ){ while ( ( getline < FILE ) > 0 ){ print $0 "," SIZE } ; close( FILE ) } ; ( NR > 1 ) && ( PREV_FILE != FILENAME ) { process_file( OLD_FNR, PREV_FILE ) } ; { PREV_FILE = FILENAME ; OLD_FNR = FNR } ; END { if ( PREV_FILE != "" ) { process_file( OLD_FNR, PREV_FILE ) } }'. where do i add the date/time option. thanks a lot.

Comment: `awk 'function process_file( SIZE, FILE ){ while ( ( getline < FILE ) > 0 ){ print $0 "," SIZE strftime("%Y%m%d") } ; close( FILE ) } ; ( NR > 1 ) && ( PREV_FILE != FILENAME ) { process_file( OLD_FNR, PREV_FILE ) } ; { PREV_FILE = FILENAME ; OLD_FNR = FNR } ; END { if ( PREV_FILE != "" ) { process_file( OLD_FNR, PREV_FILE ) } }'`